# filter: blur not working on MS Edge

Tags: css, blur, microsoft-edge, css-filters

Microsoft Edge is not supporting `filter: blur();` like it should. If I have an absolute positioned element with `filter: blur();`, inputs that appear on top will go nuts, merging with the blur (fun to watch).

Here's a Fiddle to show what happens. Works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but Edge turns into borderline epileptic. Just click the input and enjoy:
https://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/3uz0Lpfz/2/

Here's a code example:

```
<style>
  article {
    background: url(http://uzebox.org/wiki/images/1/19/Arkanoid.gif) no-repeat;
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
    -moz-filter: blur(20px);
    -o-filter: blur(20px);
    -ms-filter: blur(20px);
    filter: blur(20px);
    height: 448px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 720px;
  }

  input {
    margin: 100px 0 0 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
</style>

<article></article>
<input />
```

You can even try to place a windows explorer window on top of the fiddle, it will "interact" with the image blur, which is funny.
I tried taking a screenshot but the end result shows things as they are supposed to be, and ignores the bug (no fun :-( ).

Any ideas to go around this bug **using only** CSS?

Comment: I don't have this pinned down as I thought but I don't think Edge supports this as you are using it but I'm confused as to why it would work in IE. Filter effects shouldn't work in IE at all.

Comment: @Rob My mistake: the fiddle is not working in IE. I guess when I tested this in my website I was seeing something wrong. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: This seems to be a rendering problem specific to filters. I'd be surprised if there was a CSS workaround that didn't involve just disabling the filters outright.

Comment: By the way, `-ms-filter` refers to the proprietary implementation from IE5 onward - the prefix is never used with CSS3 filters and should be removed. I can't speak for the other prefixes.

Comment: I agree this is probably a rendering problem, since any interaction (even with other windows) will affect the blur. I guess I will have to find a different approach and forget about the CSS3. Thanks for the `-ms-filter` tip.

Comment: you would have to run it in quirk mode and allow activex eventually, but surely a bad idea since quirks mode is going to kill lots of things :).  maybe you should fall back on an rgba() color such as a lightbox look :(

Comment: IE9 will take this 
  `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='20');`  in head stuff  you need :  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"` content="IE=9">  **and finally visitor will need to have activex running** ...

Comment: @GCyrillus Thank you, that's a good point. However, I can't guarantee that all my users will have activex running, so that is not a viable solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**: This issue no longer exists in recent builds of Microsoft Edge, and should be resolved via the [Windows 10 Anniversary Update](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/06/29/windows-10-anniversary-update-available-august-2/) on August 02, 2016.

---

Thank you for reporting this issue. I work on the Microsoft Edge team, and can confirm that your fiddle reproduces the issue being described. While I don't presently have a work-around to offer, I will file this and personally notify the appropriate team(s) so as to give it earlier attention.

When I have more to share, I will return to update this answer.

Comment: Are you somehow monitoring the [tag:microsoft-edge] tag?

Comment: Absolutely  Other tags as well, as I am able.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Too bad there isn't a solution as I expected, but at least I'm glad someone is looking at the problem. Cheers.

Comment: Sampson, any idea if this is fixed now? Can you provide a link to track issue?

Comment: @AlexP This issue *does* appear to be fixed in recent builds of Microsoft Edge. Our [Anniversary Update](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/06/29/windows-10-anniversary-update-available-august-2/) goes out on August 2, so you should see this resolved for you locally (provided you apply updates) soon.

Comment: Thanks Sampson, but do you have any official link I can get confirmation. I found a bunch of reports for this issue on MS connect, but they seem to be all closed 'as duplicate' to each other. Tnx.

Comment: We have a bug filed, but I don't believe it was ever filed publicly (via bugs.microsoftedge.com). I believe this bug was filed before we launched the public bug tracker, so in the future you should be able to publicly these tickets.

Comment: @Sampson could you please tell us from which (HTML) version of Edge onwards this was corrected ? I'd like to implement an alternative to the filter for older Edge (and IE) users, and it would help to know exactly at which version Filter started behaving correctly.

Comment: Filter still doesn't work when there's an element with a higher `z-index` and `background-attachment: fixed` overlaying it. If anyone's coming here searching for a fix: remove background attachment fixed or reorder the z-indices.