# Angular Bootstrap Modal in Microsoft Edge - Background bleeding through

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, microsoft-edge

This happens on hovering over the inputs and dropdowns. It only happens in Edge, not in Chrome or IE11. Any idea what could be causing it? Apologies for the phone pic, it doesn't appear on print screen for some reason

[image]

Comment: I suspect the gpu driver here. Any instructions how to reproduce it?

Comment: This issue is related to the `filter` property, and should be resolved in Microsoft Edge 14 (which ships on August 2, 2016).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filter: blur not working on MS Edge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35727233/filter-blur-not-working-on-ms-edge)

Comment: We are in fact using the following blur classes:
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);

Looking forward to the update - thanks!